# how can I get inside of my virtual environment?

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pipenv, virtual-environment

I want to know how can I enter in my pipenv shell

there is this command :
`pipenv shell`
but every time I write this in the command line , it says "launching subshell in virtual environment...".
but I just want to get inside of that , I dont want any subshells to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following into the terminal/cmd: 
In Windows:

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

In Linux/macOS:

```
$ . venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: thank you , but I typed the command that you said (I'm on windows so the first one) and I got the error: "the module 'venv' could  not be loaded"